# unnest json data in an R column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a particular column that has data structure of such:

```
["{   \"BTC\": 1.9102,   \"USD\": -19900.5 }"]
```

the above is an example of one row.
How can I extract the json data and put them into two columns specifically columns with the names: Base and Total

Comment: Can you please post the `dput` of the first 3 rows of the `data.frame`? E.g. type `dput(df)` and then edit your post to include the output here. This should be a straightforward application of `jsonlite::fromJSON`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```r
library(rjson)
library(dplyr)

mydf <- data.frame(json = c("{   \"BTC\": 1.9102,   \"USD\": -19900.5 }",
                            "{   \"BTC\": 2.9102,   \"USD\": -29900.5 }")) 
mydf %>% rowwise %>% mutate(Base = fromJSON(json)[[1]], 
                            Total = fromJSON(json)[[2]])
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#> # Rowwise: 
#>   json                                          Base   Total
#>   <chr>                                        <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 "{   \"BTC\": 1.9102,   \"USD\": -19900.5 }"  1.91 -19900.
#> 2 "{   \"BTC\": 2.9102,   \"USD\": -29900.5 }"  2.91 -29900.
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Or using `purrr`: `map_dfr(mydf$json, fromJSON, simplifyDataFrame = TRUE)`